# How to read the contents of CERT.RSA file in Grails?

Tags: grails, certificate, apk

I renamed the apk files to zip and extracted the CERT.RSA file in grails using grails-ant.Now I want to read the contents of CERT.RSA file in grails. How exactly can I do it?

Comment: Why are you trying to read the contents? Are you trying to inspect the certificate or verify it in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
PKCS7 p7 = new PKCS7(new FileInputStream([path to CERT.RSA]))
       println p7.getCertificates()
       println p7.getContentInfo()
           println p7.getVersion()
       println p7.getSignerInfos()
```